# Neo4J dynamic data model

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Newbie alert to the world of graphs and graph modelling.
Playing with Neo4J as a native graph database.

I'm working on a usecase on developing a common (domain agnostic) product. It could be "Person" it could be "Animal" it could be "Car" and so on and so forth.

I wouldn't want to model them (and code the transformation) every time for a new domain. That makes the product a bit rigid.

What I'm thinking is to have a generic graph model by modelling Node as a 'Node' and Connection as a 'Connection' with a whole bunch of properties in them to distinguish and use them in cypher queries.

It makes me feel that it dilutes the graph data modelling but offers great flexibility. Is this the trade-off here? Any recommendations?

Are there any performance implications in this approach as I read in a few places that always modelling specific relations is much better than modelling them as a single relationship with different properties. Is this a right statement? Certainly the last thing I'd want to load the entire network (millions) in neo4j memory first and let neo4j filter it after based on properties. Or does it work smarter by indexing the properties?

Answer (score 0):

The entire neo4j ecosystem is designed and heavily optimized around *multiple* node labels and *multiple* relationship types.

As one example: the server keeps statistics about the number of instances of each label, and uses that knowledge to optimize some Cypher operations. If you decide to use a single label for all nodes (or, even decide to not use any labels at all), that will sometimes cause the Cypher Planner to create a very inefficient plan.

Certainly, as with all systems, there are things about neo4j that could be improved. But I would suggest that you gain more experience with neo4j before asserting that using it the way it is intended to be used is "a bit rigid". You may be pleasantly surprised.